# Metric Space, Induced topology

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, proof-writing

I'm trying to show that the metric topology is indeed a topology.

To do so, I want to show the following three statements are true:

1. $\emptyset$ and X are in $\tau$
2. finite intersections of open sets are open
3. arbitrary (finite, countable, uncountable ...) unions of open sets are open

I'm having trouble with part 1, that is, with what I think I need to do in order to show that $X\in\tau$.

How can I show that $\tau$ contains an open ball $B_{\epsilon}$(x) for every $x\in X$?

Comment: The metric topology is usually defined as being the topology that has open balls as a basis. For every $x\in X$, take the open ball of radius $1$. Then $X$ is the union of these.

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast. Why can we say that radius 1 works?

Comment: Sure, the ball contains $x$.

Comment: Right, but for instance, what if x is on the boundary of a subset of the real line, maybe Y=[1,4]? The ball of radius 1 around 4 isn't contained within Y. Does that mean that [1,4] with the usual metric can't induce the metric topology? Maybe it doesn't matter since the points beyond 4 are not in the set [1,4], and so are not even in the universe that we care about and thus are irrelevant

Comment: No problem. If we are working with the set $X=[1,4]$, there is nothing else in the world. The open ball of radius $1$ and centre $3.8$ will be the interval $(2.8,4]$.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks a lot for clearing this up

Comment: You are welcome. It does mean that we have to be careful about the "subspace" topology, since it is somewhat unnatural to think of $(2.8,4]$ as being open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start with a metric $d$ on a set $X$, without a topology.

You then *define* a topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$ by $$O \in \mathcal{T} \text{ iff } \forall x \in O: \exists r>0: B(x,r) \subset O\text{.}$$

Of course, one has to check that this fulfils the axioms for a topology.

To see that $X$ (what you asked about) is in $\mathcal{T}$: for any $x \in X$, we can pick any $r >0$ that we like (so e.g. $1$ will do, but $r=100$ is also OK) and the $B(x,r)$ is always a subset of $X$ (by definition, as $B(x,r) = \{ y \in X: d(x,y) < r \} \subset X$) so the condition is satisfied for any $r$.

The empty set if a bit more subtle: the condition is true vacuously (any statement that starts with $\forall x \in \emptyset$ is true, as there is no $x$ in the empty set to falsify the rest of the statement), so $\emptyset \in \mathcal{T}$.

The definition I gave is equivalent to the condition that a set is open iff it is a union of some family of open balls, which is also a common way to formulate this. Or, if the notion of a base was introduced, we take the set of open balls of $d$ as the base for a new topology, and then we check that the set of $d$-open balls satisfies the axioms for a base for a topology instead.

Answer (score 2):

The induced  topology is usually defined as the topology that has the open balls as a base. For every $x\in X$, let $B_x$ be the open ball of radius $1$ and "center" $x$, that is, the set of all points $y$ such that $d(x,y)\lt 1$. Then $X$ is the union of the $B_x$, since $x\in B_x$.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: This post is meant informative. Where necessary things are left out for clarity.*

---

*Most varieties of proves rely on the approach given by Hausdorff as follows.*

The collection of open balls with center at some chosen point is a filter base, that is:
$$\forall B_r(x),B_{r'}(x)\exists B_{r_0}(x): B_{r0}(x)\subseteq B_{r}(x)\cap B_{r'}(x)$$
(That will be our neighborhood base later: $\mathcal{B}(x)$)

The upper set induced by the filter base is a filter then:
$$\mathcal{N}(x):=\uparrow\mathcal{B}(x)$$
(That will be our neighborhood filter later: $\mathcal{N}(x)$)

*What remains for this to actually deserve the attribute neighborhood is the correlation to its chosen point and the interrelation between points.*

Let me first state this in general:
$$\forall N\in\mathcal{N}(x):\qquad x\in N$$
$$\forall N\in\mathcal{N}(x)\exists U\in\mathcal{N}(x):\qquad N\in\mathcal{N}(u),u\in U$$
In the case of metric balls that is:
$$\forall N: x\in B_r(x)\subseteq N$$
$$\forall N: B_{r(u)}(u)\subseteq B_r(x)\subseteq N$$
(The latter then can be chosen to be the open neighborhoods: $U$)

All together is called the neighborhood system:
$$x\mapsto\mathcal{N}(x)$$

*There is more to read in the [neighborhood attribute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_%28mathematics%29#Topology_from_neighbourhoods) and in the [definition via neighborhoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_category_of_topological_spaces#Definition_via_neighbourhoods).*